# Django-Ajax: Is this the most pythonic to return data to Ajax request?

Tags: python, ajax, django

`html_as_template` is just a queryset which gets displayed in `article_cards.html`, which I am refreshing (with updated data from database) via Ajax.

Two questions:

1. Is this the most "efficient" way to do so?
2. I thought `render_to_string` should also work?

```
if request.is_ajax():
    html = render_to_string('article_cards.html', context=html_as_template)
    payload = {'success': True, 'html': html}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(payload), content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: No, use a `JsonResponse`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so that would be, `return JsonResponse(payload)` in my case, or does it save me a few more more steps?

Comment: well it will not make much difference in terms of speed, etc. But it you encapsulate common logic which is always good from an architectural perspective.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I agree entirely. Just asking, do I still have to do the `payload` statement step?

Comment: In general it is not best practice to return HTML for a JSON request. Always divide data and it's representation.

Comment: @KlausD: the `html` is not raw html, it is encoded in a JSON blob. But I agree that usually JSON calls deal with structural data, not a HTML stream that might contain the data.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I removed `success: True` from the `payload` dict and it's still working. Now I'm not sure I need it at all..?